# Insert and Update multiple values in single SQL Statement

Tags: sql

We are using `Insert` statements for multi inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO [db1].[dbo].[tb1] ([ID], [CLM1], [CLM2]) 
VALUES 
('1', "A", "DB"),
('2', "AB", "BQ"),
('3', "AA", "BH"),
('4', "AD", "BT"),
('5', "AF", "EB"),
('6', "EA", "AB")
```

In the above table, ID is primary key, want to know one query with passing all values, values should update existing records and insert new records into table

Comment: SQL Server? Which version?

Comment: For SQL Server there is the [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb510625(v=SQL.120).aspx) command... but it is a pain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Merge`:

```
MERGE INTO [db1].[dbo].[tb1] AS Target
USING (
    VALUES 
    ('1', 'A', 'DB'), 
    ('2', 'AB', 'BQ'), 
    ('3', 'AA', 'BH'), 
    ('4', 'AD', 'BT'), 
    ('5', 'AF', 'EB'), 
    ('6', 'EA', 'AB')
) AS Source (new_ID, new_CLM1, new_CLM2)
ON Target.ID = Source.new_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
    ID = Source.new_ID,
    CLM1 = Source.new_CLM1,
    CLM2 = Source.new_CLM2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (ID, CLM1, CLM2) VALUES (new_ID, new_CLM1, new_CLM2);
```

[Merge Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: thank you very much, its working exactly how we wanted to be, thank you very much